# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la clase de objetos por columna de un data.frame?

Tags: r

soy nuevo en R y necesito algo de ayuda con este problema:

se creo una funcion para obtener los nombres de las columnas y la clase de datos que contiene un data.frame.

data Cereal de Lock5Data

```
     data(Cereal)

 Trb <- function(x){
          y <- names (x)
          z <- class (x)
          print (y)
          print (z)
          }
```

a pesar de que arroja los nombres de las columnas que también me interesan, la clase de objetos que contiene cada columna no son reflejados, ya que me esta dando la clase de la data en general, ¿Cómo podría mejorar esto para obtener u observar la clase de datos que contiene cada colummna en el data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claramente te dará que `class(x)` es data frame pues eso es lo que estás haciendo. Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
data(iris)

y <- lapply(iris, class)

unlist(y, use.names = TRUE)
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#>    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

Lo que se hizo fue iterar por las columnas de `iris` usando la función `lapply` y dado que el resultado es una lista, usamos la función `unlist` para dejarlo como vector.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, funciono excelente!

Comment: Mucho menos precisa pero rápida es la siguiente forma: `str(df)`